# How do I pass input parameters to sp_executesql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

In SQL Server 2014, I am trying to create a dynamic WHERE clause.

I have built the query as a string, but when I try to execute it with sp_executesql, I get the following error: 
**Líne 13 You must declare the scalar variable "@desde".**

I can't figure out how to get sp_executesql to recognize the input parameters.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[seleccionarFacturas] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @desde char(8) = null, 
    @hasta char(8) = null,
    @minimo int = null,
    @ciudad int = null
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @tiendas varchar(max);

    DECLARE @tablaFacturas TABLE
    (
        fecha char(8), 
        CO char(8),
        consecutivo varchar(max),
        nombreCliente varchar(max),
        ventaTotal int
    );

    SET @tiendas='(ID_CO=20 OR ID_CO=22 OR ID_CO=23 OR ID_CO=27 OR ID_CO=35 OR ID_CO=39 OR ID_CO=45 OR ID_CO=48 OR ID_CO=55 OR ID_CO=58)';

    DECLARE @dynamicCode nvarchar(max)=
    N'
    SELECT
        FECHA_DCTO,
        ID_CO,
        DETALLE_DOC,
        NOM_CLI_CONTADO,
        (SUM(TOT_VENTA)) AS ventaTotal
    FROM 
        moda.dbo.CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS
    WHERE'
        + @tiendas +
        N' AND FECHA_DCTO >= @desde
        AND FECHA_DCTO <= @hasta
    GROUP BY  
        DETALLE_DOC, ID_CO, FECHA_DCTO, NOM_CLI_CONTADO';

    INSERT INTO @tablaFacturas
    EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql] @dynamicCode;

    SELECT * FROM @tablaFacturas
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql] @dynamicCode;
```

Use

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @dynamicCode, 
N'@desde char(8), @hasta char(8)',
@desde = @desde, @hasta = @hasta;
```

You have to define the parameters you used in the dynamic query like`@desde  and @hasta`

Please refer [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188001.aspx)

Else You can concat the values of `@desde, @hasta` to the dynamic query,
like

```
'....FECHA_DCTO >= ' + @desde +
'AND FECHA_DCTO <= ' + @hasta +
'GROUP BY ....'
```

Comment: the concatenation one might be injected. I'd highly suggest to use the first option, where dynamic code is something like => 'field=@par_field ...'