# variable for query string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

As higher in hierarchy forum users suggested Im postig my problem as a new question related to this one: [declare variable for query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833352/declare-variable-for-query-string).

Im using dynamic query here because I want to be able to use variables (I need it for my experiment involving parameter sniffing). My query looks like that:

```
DECLARE @i NVARCHAR(10)
SET @i = 'POL'

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT

a.something1,
b.something2,
c.something3

FROM
aaa a WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN bbb b WITH(NOLOCK) ON....
LEFT JOIN ccc c WITH(NOLOCK) ON....

WHERE
a.somethingelse = ''aa''
AND
((a.entirelysomethingelse=''aaa'') OR (a.entirelysomethingelse=''aaaa''))
AND
b.anotherdifferentsomething != 41
AND 
c.yetanotherdifferentthing LIKE(''%@%'')
AND
c.datafromvariablewannabe = (@i)
GROUP BY
...
ORDER BY
...'
EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

When I want to execute my query Im getting error like:

```
'Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 28
Must declare the scalar variable "@i".'
```

When I moved declaration of variable @i into the @sql then it sorta works. Still I don't think It's what I wanted. Am I doing something wrong or it has to look like this?:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = '

DECLARE @i NVARCHAR(10)
SET @i = 'POL'

SELECT

a.something1,
b.something2,
c.something3

FROM
aaa a WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN bbb b WITH(NOLOCK) ON....
LEFT JOIN ccc c WITH(NOLOCK) ON....

WHERE
a.somethingelse = ''aa''
AND
((a.entirelysomethingelse=''aaa'') OR (a.entirelysomethingelse=''aaaa''))
AND
b.anotherdifferentsomething != 41
AND 
c.yetanotherdifferentthing LIKE(''%@%'')
AND
c.datafromvariablewannabe = (@i)
GROUP BY
...
ORDER BY
...'
EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

Are there any mistakes in my code so Im getting MSG137 error or it's just impossible task that I want to do here.

I don't want to create a stored procedure from this query. I want to be able to use variables but without relying on stored procedure.

I apologize admins/forum users for problems involving my earlier question in hyperlinked question.

Comment: what does this mean `When I moved declaration of variable @i into the @sql then it sorta works. Still I don't think It's what I wanted`

Comment: variables are scoped to a batch and exec runs in seperate batch,so you have to include it in same @sql

Comment: I meant that I got good result but the method of getting those results was not the one that I was searching for. I didn't know that i have to "break" the query string (as @mortb sugessted) so my variable would be able to be "loaded?" in there.

Comment: Off-topic but worth a read: [the downside of using NoLock](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/).  I'm sure you have your reasons but it is worth highlighting that NoLock can return duplicates, deleted records, and other stuff you most likely don't want in a production query.  See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516139/how-do-i-pass-input-parameters-to-sp-executesql) for an alternative method on passing variables into dynamical SQL.

Comment: I know that nolock have it's downsides but using it here is an order from my chief and in this case it won't do any harm. Still usefull comment though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "break" the string. The value @i is not available in the scope the string is executed in, so you need to make it part of the string.
Like so:

```
DECLARE @tmp NVARCHAR(10)
SET @tmp = 'POL'

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT

a.something1,
b.something2,
c.something3

FROM
aaa a WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN bbb b WITH(NOLOCK) ON....
LEFT JOIN ccc c WITH(NOLOCK) ON....

WHERE
a.somethingelse = ''aa''
AND
((a.entirelysomethingelse=''aaa'') OR (a.entirelysomethingelse=''aaaa''))
AND
b.anotherdifferentsomething != 41
AND 
c.yetanotherdifferentthing LIKE(''%@%'')
AND
c.datafromvariablewannabe = (@i)
GROUP BY
...
ORDER BY
...
OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR(@i = ''' + @tmp + '''))'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@i NVARCHAR(255)', @i = @tmp
```

Comment: This is the answer that I was searching for. Still I needed to add quotation marks to @i variable. So It has to look like that:
`DECLARE @i nvARCHAR(10)

SET @i ='''POL'''`

Comment: There is one more thing. If I'd want to add here `option (optimize for @i)` where or how should I do that? In this particular case.

Comment: After the ORDER BY Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx It is specific to one query statement (you should  put it last in you SELECT statement)

Comment: I tried: 
`option (optimize for ('+ @i +' = ''POL'')` 
and `option (optimize for (@i = 'POL'))`
and `option (optimize for ('+@i+' = '''POL''')` but it's not working. It's working within 2nd query from my question but I can't get it right within query from your answer... Im getting 
`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 39
Incorrect syntax near 'POL'.`

Comment: (optimize for ('+ @i +') Explanation: you have already assigned the value 'POL' to the variable @i. ' + @i + ' will assign the value of @i into your string

Comment: If I understood correctly it should look like that:
`...
ORDER BY
...
option(optimize for (' + @i + '))` but it's not working. Im still getting the same error.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I edited the SQL statement. You should probably use SP_EXECUTESQL instead of EXEC. Then you can input real parameters to your sql statement

Comment: Im sorry but Im still confused. Could you post it as an answer and tell me some more how to use it? It seems that I have to make another variable and I don't really know why and where? Sorry for the trouble but Im still an unexperienced trainee. I tried to use the part of the code that you fixed but I got two more error mesages: `Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@tmp".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 44
Must declare the scalar variable "@tmp".`

Comment: Wouldn't `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

The working solution with optimize for @variable would look like that:

```
DECLARE @i NVARCHAR(255)
declare @tmp nvarchar(255)
SET @tmp = 'POL'

DECLARE @SQL nVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT

a.something1,
b.something2,
c.something3

FROM
aaa a WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN bbb b WITH(NOLOCK) ON....
LEFT JOIN ccc c WITH(NOLOCK) ON....

WHERE
a.somethingelse = ''aa''
AND
((a.entirelysomethingelse=''aaa'') 
OR 
(a.entirelysomethingelse=''aaaa''))
AND
b.anotherdifferentsomething != 41
AND 
c.yetanotherdifferentthing LIKE(''%@%'')
AND
c.datafromvariablewannabe = (@i)

GROUP BY
...
ORDER BY
...

OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR(@i = ''' + @tmp + '''))'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@i NVARCHAR(255)', @i = @tmp
```

It didn't worked without declaring variable `@temp`. After that I encountered a problem with Exec. I couldn't use `SP_EXECUTESQL` as @mortb suggested. I had to use `EXECUTE` before `SP_EXECUTESQL` and I found some information related to next error in that post [Why do I get "Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'." when I try to use sp_executesql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743890/why-do-i-get-procedure-expects-parameter-statement-of-type-ntext-nchar-nvar). I had to change type for a query variable and get ridd of brackets.

Still I would like to know why I had to create new variable and It'd be helpful to know a little bit more about this part of code:

```
OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR(@i = ''' + @tmp + '''))'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@i NVARCHAR(255)', @i = @tmp
```

It works now but I'd like to know why and how?

Comment: `SP_EXECUTESQL` is a built in stored procedure that takes a string of SQL and runs it with the specified parameters. It is confusing in the beginning when you make sql from a string. The part `N'@i NVARCHAR(255)', @i = @tmp` tells the stored procedure that there will be a parameter in the sql text that is named `@i` and that `@i` (when the text executes) should have the same value `@tmp` has "outside" the text. The part `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR(@i = ''' + @tmp + '''))'` means the text will *contain the value of* `@tmp` (it is no longer a variable when the text is fed into `SP_EXECUTESQL`).

Comment: Give it some time and you will understand :)