# How do I replace the yyyymmdd to pick the latest month end date for Table Name

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create an automated SQL agent job which will run on a monthly basis and load data into a new table with the month end date every time the job runs. How do I replace the yyyymmdd to pick the latest month end date

```
IF OBJECT_ID('DataMart.dbo.tablename_yyyymmdd') IS NOT NULL 
DROP Table DataMart.dbo.tablename_yyyymmdd
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Student Data load completed'
    SELECT *
    INTO DataMart.dbo.tablename_yyyymmdd
    FROM 
    ( SELECT * FROM [DataMart].[dbo].[stutable_yyyymmdd]
) T;END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following steps could be taken.

1. The `convert()` function is capable of [outputting a variety of date format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
2. Subsequently, your query string can be constructed by concatenation and executed using `exec sp_executesql`.

Also note that this is definitely not the safest way for automated use. Please also consider refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516139/how-do-i-pass-input-parameters-to-sp-executesql) to prevent arbitrary string execution.

```
/* 1. get yyyymmdd */
declare @s char(8) = convert(varchar, getdate(), 112);
print @s;

/* 2. build query and run */
declare @sql nvarchar(max);  -- sp_executesql expects nvarchar
set @sql = '    
    IF OBJECT_ID(''testdb.dbo.tablename_' + @s + ''') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP Table testdb.dbo.tablename_' + @s + ';

    BEGIN
        PRINT ''Student Data load completed''
        SELECT *
        INTO testdb.dbo.tablename_' + @s + '
        FROM 
        ( SELECT * FROM [testdb].[dbo].[stutable_' + @s + ']
    ) T;
    END;
';

print @sql;
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Tested on SQL Server 2017 (linux docker image, the latest version)